# Receive JSON without '\0'

Tags: java, json

I have to integrate my application with an existing (not modifiable) Python script which sends the JSON messages without '\0' or any other "end-of-message" character. Is there any better way to handle incoming messages that just to read data from the socket byte after byte and count brackets? In this application sending `{` or `}` in message content is illegal due to the protocol so this code works fine but seems to me ugly:

```
  int i = 0;
  int brackets = 0;
  byte[] msg = new byte[4096];
  do
  {
       byte chunk = reader.readByte();
       msg[i++] = chunk;
       if (chunk == 123)  // check if '{'
           brackets++;
       else if (chunk == 125) // check if '}'
           brackets--;
  } while ( brackets > 0);
  byte[] finalMsg = Arrays.copyOfRange(msg, 0, i);
```

**EDIT** Python code:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((server_ip, server_port))
logging.info('Connected to: %s', (server_ip, server_port))
s.send(json.dumps(data))
logging.info('Sent message: %s', json.dumps(data))
```

I analyse text using bytes because this script sends each character as a single byte and as far as I know `char` is 2 bytes long in Java. When I tried to receive data char-after-char I was not able to compare them with `{` and `}`.

Comment: Why are you processing *text* with a *byte* array? How is the Python script "sending" JSON messages? We need a lot more information.

Comment: How are you exchanging the JSON messages anyway? This is something a transport protocol should be handling. (And HTTP handles.)

Comment: @Yob Also, that hack with counting brackets wont work at all. Here's why: `{ a: 1, b: '}' }`

Comment: Oh. You're not using *any* transport protocol / rolling your own. This is a terrible idea. Replace the raw sockets with, at least, [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) if nothing more robust.

Comment: @Max: I know that counting brackets is not a correct solution, but as I said we are certain that there won't be any "additional brackets" in messages. Anyway: I agree that this approach is simply not elegant so I'm asking whether there is any possibility to do this in any other way.

Comment: @millimoose: As I said: there is no way to change the transport protocol. I'm writing a university project with people who has already implemented this in various languages (C#, C++, Python, Ruby) and they have no time to change their code. I simply have to adjust my solution although this approach is not the best possible.

Comment: @Yob Sorry, I missed the "non-modifiable" bit. Well, at least it's a lesson learned. What coult be more "elegant" is writing your own real(-ish) JSON parser, at least one that handles strings and nested objects. If you're not pressed for time, you could look into [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)? I seem to recall that tool made it feasible to hack up a quick recursive-descent parser.

Comment: @Yob According to the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) you are right about the size of `char` in Java. They list char as a `16-bit Unicode character`.

Comment: Java uses 2-byte chars internally, but to convert between those and C-style one-byte char strings one should usually use UTF8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coud use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonReader jr = new JsonReader(reader);
String msg1 = gson.toJson(gson.fromJson(jr, Object.class));
String msg2 = gson.toJson(gson.fromJson(jr, Object.class));
...
```

Where `reader` is input stream from socket reader.